# Getting an "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" error inside a do While Loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Jogo {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int tipoJogo;
int turno;
Barco[] jfA,jfB;
Random random = new Random();

public Jogo(Barco[]fA, Barco[]fB, int tamanhomax, int tj)
{
    for(int i =0;i<tamanhomax;i++)
    {
        fA[i]=fB[i]=null;
    }

    jfA = fA;
    jfB = fB;
    tipoJogo=tj;
}



//public Barco[] getFrota() {
//  return frota;
//}
int linhaAC = random.nextInt(7);
int colunaAC = random.nextInt(7);
int orientação = random.nextInt(1);



public Jogo(int TipoJogo){
    TipoJogo = tipoJogo;
}
public  void manual1(){
    System.out.println("Jogador A");
    System.out.println("Insira as coordenadas do Aircraft Carrier e a sua orientação(0 horizontal, 1 vertical):");
    //linhaAC = scanner.nextInt();
    //colunaAC = scanner.nextInt();

    String op= scanner.nextLine();

    int linhaAC = (int) Character.toUpperCase(op.charAt(0))-'A'; //vai buscar o primeiro caracter da String op e transforma do A ao I em interiros 0 a 8
    int colunaAC = (int) op.charAt(1)-'1';
    int orientação = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(linhaAC +"  -  " + colunaAC);


    do{

        System.out.println("Fora do tabuleiro");
        System.out.println("Insira de novo as coordenadas do Aircraft Carrier:  ");
        linhaAC= (int) Character.toUpperCase(op.charAt(0))-'A';
        colunaAC = (int) op.charAt(1)-'1';
        orientação = scanner.nextInt();

    }while((colunaAC > 4 && orientação == 0)|| (linhaAC > 'D' && orientação == 1));
```

Ok iam getting the following error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Jogo.manual1(Jogo.java:147)
at Main.start(Main.java:134)
at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

This happen when i try to set a new value for variables LinhaAC and ColunaAC inside the do while loop.

Basically if i set LinhaAC to be greater than 'D' or ColunaAC to be greater than 4 it starts the Do while loop where i ask the user to insert new values to those variables.

So when i try to set new values, after i insert LinhaAC and ColunaAC i press enter so i can choose the new value for "orientação" it triggers the error.

It only happens inside the do while group. In the first time i insert the values it doesn't give any error.

EDIT: It happens even if i use the same value i choose in the first time. Its not like iam inserting an int on an scanner.next();

Comment: what is the type of `Barco`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fix it.

```
public  void manual1(){
    System.out.println("Jogador A");
    System.out.println("Insira as coordenadas do Aircraft Carrier e a sua 
     orientação(0 horizontal, 1 vertical):");
    //linhaAC = scanner.nextInt();
    //colunaAC = scanner.nextInt();

    String op= scanner.next();

    int linhaAC = (int) Character.toUpperCase(op.charAt(0))-'A';
    int colunaAC = (int) op.charAt(1)-'1';
    int orientação = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(linhaAC +"  -  " + colunaAC);


    while((colunaAC >= 4 && orientação == 0) || (linhaAC >= 4 && orientação == 1)){

        System.out.println("Fora do tabuleiro");
        System.out.println("Insira de novo as coordenadas do Aircraft Carrier:  ");
        op= scanner.next();
        linhaAC=(int)Character.toUpperCase(op.charAt(0))-'A';
        colunaAC = (int) op.charAt(1)-'1';
        orientação = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(linhaAC +"  -  " + colunaAC);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. The reason is that you get `InputMismatchException` because of your input is did not match with the variable type.

You are taking three inputs their types should be match.

That's the reason for these error messages:

```
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
```

As a Example:

```
orientação = scanner.nextInt();
```

This line expect integer value but if you add `String` to it gives you `InputMismatchException`

Solution:

To avoid this you can handle input type if it is not integer you can display proper message by `try-catch block`.

```
try{
    orientação = scanner.nextInt();
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Enter only integer");
}
```

Or you can print the error message like,

```
//...
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Likewise do this for every input you get from the keyboard. This will avoid error messages and make your program more easy to handle.

Learn more about [exception handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).